# Deriving Aeson type classes with two different possible types in the same field

Tags: haskell, type-parameter, aeson, to-json, fromjson

I have an API which returns JSON results in the following form:

```json
{
  "data": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

The `data` field can be the encoding of two distinct records which are shown below:

```hs
newtype ResultsTypeA = ResultsTypeA [ResultTypeA]
newtype ResultsTypeB = ResultsTypeB [ResultTypeB]
```

When I query this API from Haskell, I know in advance whether I'm dealing with a `ResultsTypeA` or a `ResultsTypeB` because I'm explicitly asking for it in the query.

The part where I'm struggling is with the Aeson `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` instances. Since both result types `A` and `B` are ultimately lists of `Int`, I can't use pattern matcher in `FromJSON`, because I could only match a `[Int]` in both cases.

This is why I thought of doing the following:

```hs
newType ApiResponse a =
    ApiResponse {
        data :: a
    }

newtype ResultsTypeA = ResultsTypeA [ResultTypeA]
newtype ResultsTypeB = ResultsTypeB [ResultTypeB]
```

However I can't get my head around how to write the `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` instances for the above, because now `ApiResponse` has a type parameter, and nowhere in Aeson docs seem to be a place where it is explained how to derive these instances with a type parameter involved.

Another alternative, avoiding a type parameter, would be the following:

```hs
newtype Results =
    ResultsTypeA [ResultTypeA]
  | ResultsTypeB [ResultTypeB]

newtype ApiResponse =
    ApiResponse {
        data :: Results
    }
```

In this case the `ToJSON` is straightforward:

```hs
instance ToJSON ApiResponse where
    toJSON = genericToJSON $ defaultOptions
```

But the `FromJSON` gets us back to the problem of not being able to decide between result types `A` and `B`...

It is also possible that I'm doing it wrong entirely and there is a third option I wouldn't see.

- how would the `FromJSON` / `ToJSON` instances look like with a type parameter on `ApiResponse`?
- is there a better alternative completely different from anything exposed above to address this?

Comment: I'm not convinced it makes sense to have any Haskell types for this dedicated purpose _at all_. Sometimes it's the best to just work with [`Value`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.5.6.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:Value)s at the interface, and then extract the relevant data into Haskell types that don't bother approximating the JSON structure in any way.

Comment: I think you should be able to derive `FromJSON` and `ToJSON` for parameterized types just fine. The generated instance will be of the form `FromJSON a => FromJSON (ApiResponse  a)`. You should also derive instances for `ResultsTypeA`, `ResultTypeA`, and so on. The ones for the `ResultTypeA` should piggyback on the underlying  instances for `Int`. This can be done with `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` and `DerivingStrategies`: `deriving newtype (FromJSON, ToJSON)`

Comment: Frame challenge: what's wrong with just using `[Int]`?  *Especially* given "When I query this API from Haskell, I know in advance whether I'm dealing with a `ResultsTypeA` or a `ResultsTypeB` because I'm explicitly asking for it in the query.". If you absolutely must have two distinct types, the querier can just apply the appropriate `newtype` constructor, but even that is, in most cases, just not needed.

Answer (score 2):

> Since both result types A and B are ultimately lists of Int, I can't use pattern matcher in FromJSON, because I could only match a [Int] in both cases.

If you have a parameterized type, and you are writing a `FromJSON` instance by hand, you can put the precondition that the parameter must itself have a `FromJSON` instance.

Then, when you are writing the parser, you can use the parser for the type parameter as part of your definition. Like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Aeson

data ApiResponse a =
    ApiResponse {
        _data :: a,
        other :: Bool
    } 

instance FromJSON a => FromJSON (ApiResponse a) where
    parseJSON = withObject "" $ \o -> 
          ApiResponse <$> o .: "data" -- we are using the parameter's FromJSON 
                      <*> o .: "other"
```

Now, let's define two newtypes that borrow their respective `FromJSON` instances from that of `Int`, using `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies #-}
-- Make the instances for the newtypes exactly equal to that of Int
newtype ResultTypeA = ResultTypeA Int deriving newtype FromJSON
newtype ResultTypeB = ResultTypeB Int deriving newtype FromJSON
```

If we load the file in ghci, we can supply the type parameter to `ApiResponse` and [interrogate the available instances](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:instances):

```
ghci> :instances ApiResponse [ResultTypeA]
instance FromJSON (ApiResponse [ResultTypeA])
```

---

You can also auto-derive `FromJSON` for `ApiResponse`, if you also derive `Generic`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies #-}
import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics

data ApiResponse a =
    ApiResponse {
        _data :: a,
        other :: Bool
    } 
    deriving stock Generic
    deriving anyclass FromJSON
```

`deriving stock Generic` makes GHC generate a representation of the datatype's structure that can be used to derive implementations for other typeclasses—here, `FromJSON`. For those derivations to be made through the `Generic` machinery, they need to use the [`anyclass`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/deriving_strategies.html) method.

The generated instance will be of the form `FromJSON a => FromJSON (ApiResponse a)`, just like the hand-written one. We can check it again in ghci:

```
ghci> :set -XPartialTypeSignatures
ghci> :set -Wno-partial-type-signatures
ghci> :instances ApiResponse _
instance FromJSON w => FromJSON (ApiResponse w)
instance Generic (ApiResponse w)
```